# Conditionally update a set attribute and keep track of it's number of elements in it DynamoDB Node.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm keeping a list of followers and tracking the size of the list simultaneously

I have an attribute that's a String Set and another attribute that tracks the number of elements in the String Set. I do this by updating both attributes simultaneously. As a guard, I only want the number to increment when the new element doesn't already exist in the Set. The Set by nature won't update if the element is already in it.

Here're the params I use for the update call:

```
const paramsForUpdatingUserBeingFollowed = {
    TableName: process.env.usersTableName,
    Key: {
      userId: userBeingFollowed
    },
    ConditionExpression: "NOT(contains(isFollowedBy, :userMakingRequest))",
    UpdateExpression:
      "ADD isFollowedBy :userMakingRequest, isFollowedByCount :num",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":userMakingRequest":
        dynamoDbLib.docClient.createSet([userMakingRequest]) || null,
      ":num": 1
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
  };
```

I expect the update action to fail if an element already exists in the set. The condition expression appears to have no effect; the attribute still gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to contains should always be a string!

I was passing in a SET, hence the unpredictable behavior.

These params produce the behavior I'm looking for:

```
const paramsForUpdatingUserBeingFollowed = {
    TableName: process.env.usersTableName,
    Key: {
      userId: userBeingFollowed
    },
    ConditionExpression: "NOT(contains(isFollowedBy, :userMakingRequestStr))",
    UpdateExpression:
      "ADD isFollowedBy :userMakingRequest, isFollowedByCount :num",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":userMakingRequest":
        dynamoDbLib.docClient.createSet([userMakingRequest]) || null,
      ":userMakingRequestStr": userMakingRequest || null,
      ":num": 1
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
  };
```